# Azure IoT Hub change protocol from AMQP to HTTP

Tags: http, azure, service, amqp

MS tells all the time, that it is possible to choose between AMQP and HTTP in their IoT-Hub... 
But I can't find anywhere how that shall work. 
I forget to mention, that I've got a solution for the client:

```
DeviceClient.Create(iotHubUri, new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(deviceID, deviceKey), TransportType.Http1);
```

But I don't know how to change the cloud-server

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change anything service side, just your client change will be sufficient.

Your client software design will need to change depending on the protocol. For example for cloud to device messages you'll need to poll to receive messages. See the section "Choosing your communication protocol" in the [Microsoft Azure IoT Hub developer guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-devguide/).

Also currently there is an issue with cloud to device messages with Http1 protocol in that the message is marked as `Rejected` whether `CompleteAsync()` or `RejectAsync()` is called. For updates on when this will be fixed please see this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/issues/63) on github.

Comment: I solved my personal problem:
I couldn't connect because of a DNS- and firewall-problem in my company.

Comment: Yes, it's good to see the "Rejected" issue is now fixed, glad you got your problem sorted.

Comment: Remember that client side supports both AMQP and HTTP but service side supports AMQP only